# Include JS script into meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

Let's say I have the following script in my old HTML file which I'd like to port to meteor

```
    <script>
    //recursivly go through JSON file
    function recursiveGetProperty(obj, lookup, callback) {
        for (property in obj) {
            if (property == lookup) {
                callback(obj[property]);
            } else if (obj[property] instanceof Object) {
                recursiveGetProperty(obj[property], lookup, callback);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

I would like to include that under index.js

```
  /client
     index.html
     index.js
```

I tried to wrap the script with Template.index.events{} but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you put the code (without the script tags of course) in index.js, and then you can define an onclick handler (on say a button) which calls recursiveGetProperty ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<script>` tag. Just paste your function on `index.js` and you are good to go.

Comment: I must admit that I felt quite stupid asking that question.
Turns out I could just put it in  `Template.index.rendered = function(){
//code goes here
};`